A Stirling's approximation for the generalized incomplete gamma function
I am dealing with the so called generalized incomplete Gamma function defined as
$$\Gamma(z,x,y):=\int_{x}^{y}t^{z-1}{\rm e}^{-t} dt\quad(0<x<y,,\,\Re(z)>0).$$
In the case $z\in\mathbb{R}$, it is weel known that, by an application of the saddle-point method for example, that taking $x=z-f(z)$ and $y=z+f(z)$ with $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)/\sqrt z=+\infty$ yields
$$\Gamma(z,z-f(z),z+f(z))\sim \Gamma(z)\sim \sqrt{2\pi}z^{z-1/2}{\rm e}^{-z}.$$
I wonder if this asymptotics holds when $z$ is complex with $|{\rm arg}\,z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ taking even wider bounds, $x=\frac{|z|}{\xi(|z|)}$ and $y=|z|\xi(|z|)$ where $\xi(v)$ is a slowly increasing function of $v$ (typically $\xi(v)=\log(v)$). My assumption is that it doesn't and that it depends on the argument of $z$ but I have no clue how to show it.
Thus, my first question is, do we have an asymptotics for
$$\Gamma\Big(z,\frac{|z|}{\xi(|z|)},|z|\xi(|z|)\Big)\quad\Big(|z|\to\infty,\,|\arg z|<\frac{\pi}{2}\Big).$$
My second question is, assuming $x<|z|<y$, what are the conditions over $x$, $y$ and $z$ for
$$\Gamma(z,x,y)\sim\Gamma(z)$$
to hold?

Taking $t=z\mathrm{e}^s$, we can write
\begin{align*}
\Gamma (z,x,y) &= \int_x^y {t^{z - 1} {\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t}  = z^z {\rm e}^{ - z} \int_{ - \log (z/x)}^{\log (y/z)} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s} \\ & = z^z {\rm e}^{ - z} \int_{ - \log (\left| z \right|/x) - {\rm i}\arg z}^{\log (y/\left| z \right|) - {\rm i}\arg z} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s} .
\end{align*}
Now, by Cauchy's theorem,
\begin{align*}
0 = \;&\int_{ - \log (\left| z \right|/x)}^{\log (y/\left| z \right|)} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s}  + \int_{\log (y/\left| z \right|)}^{\log (y/\left| z \right|) - {\rm i}\arg z} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s} \\ & - \int_{ - \log (\left| z \right|/x) - {\rm i}\arg z}^{\log (y/\left| z \right|) - {\rm i}\arg z} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s}  + \int_{ - \log (\left| z \right|/x) - {\rm i}\arg z}^{ - \log (\left| z \right|/x)} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s} .
\end{align*}
If we assume that $\left| {\arg z} \right| \le \frac{\pi }{2} - \delta$ ($<\frac{\pi }{2}$) and $\frac{y}{{\left| z \right|}}\to  + \infty$, $\frac{{\left| z \right|}}{x} \to  + \infty$ as $|z|\to+\infty$, then the integrals on the finite segments will vanish as $z\to\infty$. Thus,
$$
\int_{ - \log (\left| z \right|/x) - {\rm i}\arg z}^{\log (y/\left| z \right|) - {\rm i}\arg z} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s}  = \int_{ - \log (\left| z \right|/x)}^{\log (y/\left| z \right|)} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s}  + o(1)
$$
for large $z$, under the above assumptions. By the usual Laplace-method argument, the main contribution to the integral comes from a small neighbourhood of $s=0$, and
\begin{align*}
\sqrt z \int_{ - \log (\left| z \right|/x)}^{\log (y/\left| z \right|)} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s} & \sim \sqrt z \int_{ - \delta }^\delta  {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm d}s}  \sim \sqrt z \int_{ - \delta }^\delta  {{\rm e}^{ - z\frac{{s^2 }}{2}} {\rm d}s} \\ & = \sqrt 2 \int_{ - \delta \sqrt {z/2} }^{\delta \sqrt {z/2} } {{\rm e}^{ - t^2 } {\rm d}t}  \to \sqrt {2\pi }. 
\end{align*}
In summary, if $\frac{y}{{\left| z \right|}}\to  + \infty$ and $\frac{{\left| z \right|}}{x} \to  + \infty$ as $|z|\to+\infty$, then
$$
\Gamma (z,x,y) \sim \sqrt {2\pi } z^{z-1/2}\mathrm{e}^{-z}\sim \Gamma(z),
$$
as $z\to\infty$ in the sector $\left| {\arg z} \right| \le \frac{\pi }{2} - \delta$ ($<\frac{\pi }{2}$).

Thank you for your very helpful answer!
